# Bash using getopts doesn't return expected echo value

Tags: bash

I'm attempting to check if one of two flags exists. Either `-c` or `-v`.

However, on attempting to run the below I'm finding that the script exits without outputting anything.

I've had a look at changing the position of the colon in the `while getopts “:v:” opts; do` statement and this appears to change nothing.

Any ideas?

```
#Check that the $ACTION variable is of the form “-[character]"
if [[ ! $ACTION =~ ^-. ]] ; then
    echo "2";
    printHelp;
    exit 1;
fi 

#Too many arguments passed
if [[ ${#ACTION} -gt 2 ]] ; then
    echo "3";
    printHelp;
    exit 1;
fi

#Use cases for correct characters
while getopts “:v:” opts; do
    echo "4";
    case $opts in
        v)      echo "1234" #vocabTest;
                echo "${bold}STARTING VOCAB TEST:${reset}"
                break
                ;;
        c)      #phraseTest;
                echo "${bold}STARTING PHRASE TEST:${reset}"
                exit 0
                ;;
        ?)      echo "";
                printHelp
                exit 1
                ;;
    esac
done                    


}
```

Comment: Remove the last `:`. The quotes you have in your example are weird quotes and won't be read properly in a bash script, use normal ones like `"` not `“`

Comment: You also need `c` in the `getopts` arg string if you expect that to be a valid argument.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I removed the entire while loop as it was not serving any purpose. The below ended up working:

```
    ##########################################################################################
# Check args passed to the script                                                        #
##########################################################################################
ACTION=$1;

#Check that the $ACTION variable is of the form “-[character]"
if [[ ! $ACTION =~ ^-. ]] ; then
    printHelp;
    exit 1;
fi 

#Too many arguments passed
if [[ ${#ACTION} -gt 2 ]] ; then
    printHelp;
    exit 1;
fi

#Use cases for correct characters
case ${ACTION} in
    (-v)    echo "${bold}STARTING VOCAB TEST:${reset}"
            ;;
    c)      #phraseTest;
            echo "${bold}STARTING PHRASE TEST:${reset}"
            exit 0
            ;;
    ?)      echo "";
            printHelp
            #exit 1
            ;;
esac
```

Comment: The getopts is for all the command line args, what you have written will not work.

Comment: This isn't at all equivalent as it doesn't process any command line arguments.

Comment: @EtanReisner you're absolutely right. In the end I wasn't looking to parse arguments, but rather that a flag had been added. So while this does 'fix' the issue, it doesn't fix the (wrong) question I was asking.